# SLURM: Running one job on multiple nodes? (using python joblib)

Tags: python, slurm, joblib

I'm trying to run my python program on a cluster managed by SLURM (which I am new to). I used python joblib for parallelizing some for loops within my program. Is there a way to run my job (consisting of only my  program, so *only one task*) on multiple nodes so that it can access more CPUs than in just one node?

EDIT:
Following [this](https://youtu.be/ULRSFk5s7xM?t=325) (but of course calling mpriun from my sbatch file), it throws an error before the last-ranked process:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arisMPI.py", line 4, in <module>
    comm.Barrier()
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 567, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Barrier
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Unknown error class, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(289).....................: MPI_Barrier(comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
PMPI_Barrier(275).....................: 
MPIR_Barrier_impl(175)................: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra_auto(110)..........: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra_dissemination(49)..: 
MPIDU_Complete_posted_with_error(1137): Process failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arisMPI.py", line 4, in <module>
    comm.Barrier()
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 567, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Barrier
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Unknown error class, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(289).....................: MPI_Barrier(comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
PMPI_Barrier(275).....................: 
MPIR_Barrier_impl(175)................: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra_auto(110)..........: 
MPIR_Barrier_intra_dissemination(49)..: 
MPIDU_Complete_posted_with_error(1137): Process failed
```

Do you happen to have an inkling what that might be about? It doesn't happen when running on only one node. I googled but couldn't find a definite answer, only other people that ran into the same issue.

EDIT: The porblem was that mpi4py linked to a different MPI than the one from my cluster. Uninstalling mpi4py and setting the right mpicc path during mpi4py installation solved this.

Comment: You will have to parallelize your program with MPI (or any other way of inter-node communication). Then start your code inside the job with `srun`. It will run one task per node, where each task will communicate with each other to get the work done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is almost working now, but I ran into an issue (see my Edit) :(

Comment: Can you post youur code, and how you are calling it?